# There is no vmnet8 in "Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/"

Tags: macos, vmware

I can not find `vmnet8` in `Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/`,
My OS is macOS Mojave 10.14.5,and Vmware Fusion is 8.1.1 (3771013).

There are only preferences, preferences-private in the directory.

[image]

Comment: What is your actual problem, or what are you trying to do?

Comment: If the image is supposed to be an indication of where you're looking for it, you're in the wrong place. You're in `~/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/` not  `/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/`

Comment: sorry  ，Let me describe my purpose。I want to fix the IP of the virtual machine that is CentOS 7.3 by NAT，and let Other hosts on the LAN can also access it。 So ，According to the online way，I need to modify the vmnet8 in “～/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/”   but there is not